# Using login and password authentification in IBM MQ

Tags: authentication, ibm-mq

I'm a little bit confused with authentication methods in IBM MQ. 
It looks like the system encourage to use LDAP.

I tested it and it works fine.

But is it possible to have just simple combination of login + password?

Just setup login and password for queue manager and then used it during connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use user ID and password checked against the queue manager O/S or checked against the LDAP server the queue manager is using.

It depends on how your queue manager is configured. Issue the following commands to discover which.

```
DISPLAY QMGR CONNAUTH

DISPLAY AUTHINFO(<name-from-CONNAUTH>) ALL
```

Comment: Thanks. I just looked for a simpler way to do without creating an account  in OS or LDAP, but looks like it is not possible

Comment: @Neir0 - there are various vendor provided solutions that have other options if you want to buy something that doesn't come with the Base MQ product. Whatever you do, the user id + password you want to pass in for a simple authentication has to be stored somewhere for the check to be made. In my view the O/S is the easiest to work with, but as I say there are other options. In your mind, where would you like the user id and password to be stored?

Comment: In some inner DB like it is done in many other applications. Account that I'm going to use will manage permissions on app level. I used to think that OS account should manage permissions on OS level (like access to the file system). I'm pretty sure this approach might be fine and developers had some reasons to implement it but I personally don't feel like it is natural choice.

Comment: As I said in my earlier response there are vendor solutions that provide 'other places' to define your userid and passwords to check. They require you to purchase a solution on top of IBM MQ. Only things provided with IBM MQ itself are O/S and LDAP.